# MVC 5 with facebook helper error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Im having MVC5 App and use the  facebook.helper package  and Identity. and I got get an error

```
Line 218:    private static SimpleMembershipProvider GetMembershipProvider() {
Line 219:        var provider = Membership.Provider as SimpleMembershipProvider;
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add the `WebMatrix.Data.dll`  Via nuget,
Give it a try and let me know .